# Enemy movement problem with Velocity in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Why Unity 2D enemy movement stop sometimes (only few tiles go ahead when using velocity) but i pushed it again , enemy moved. what is the problem?
I can move that using transform and addforce. but the problem is the velocity.

```
public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5;
    private Rigidbody2D _rBody;

    void Awake()
    {
        _rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 vector2 = new Vector2(moveSpeed, _rBody.velocity.y);
        _rBody.velocity = vector2;
    }
}
```

transform, addforce movement is working perfectly.
**I want to move the enemy using velocity without stopping until it is destroyed.**

Comment: You might need to change your "Rigidbody type" into Kinematic

Comment: when I use that what happens to the gravity?

Comment: When you use Kinematic, the rigidbody will not be affected by forces or gravity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the wrong "body type" in Rigidbody2D on your Enemy object. You should change it to "Kinematic" or "Dynamic".